# Invalid Date error when using computed value to set data value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating single page component in Vue which uses date object to initialize date picker. The odd thing is that the value is calculated properly in `created()` function but wrong in render time of the Vue objects. Now my guess is that in one case the parameter of `new Date(milliseconds)` is taken as int (which is good) but in second case it is a String, hence the "Invalid Date" error.

```
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-md pa-1>
    <v-layout fluid>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-card elevation="2">
          <v-container fluid grid-list-lg>
            <v-layout wrap>
              <v-flex xs6>
                <div>Start date: {{ dateToString(startDate) }} <v-btn @click="console.log('start change clicked')">Change</v-btn></div>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs6>
                <div>End date: {{ dateToString(endDate) }} <v-btn @click="console.log('end change clicked')">Change</v-btn></div>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <v-dialog
                      v-model="dialog"
                      width="500"
                    >
                      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <v-btn
                          color="blue"
                          dark
                          v-on="on"
                        >
                          Click Me
                        </v-btn>
                      </template>

                      <v-card>
                        <v-card-title
                          class="headline grey lighten-2"
                          primary-title
                        >
                          Privacy Policy
                        </v-card-title>

                        <v-card-text>
                          <v-date-picker v-model="startDatePicked"></v-date-picker>
                        </v-card-text>
                      </v-card>
                    </v-dialog>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GeographicStatistics",
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      startDate: new Date(this.startDateMs),
      endDate: new Date(Date.now()),
      startDatePicked: new Date(Date.now() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      endDatePicked: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    };
  },
  computed: {
    startDateMs() {
      console.log("compute start date ms from end date: " + this.endDateMs);
      return this.endDateMs - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    },
    endDateMs() {
      console.log("compute start date ms");
      return Date.now();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dateToString(date) {
      return date.toLocaleString();
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("date s: " + this.startDate + ", e: " + this.endDate);
    console.log("calulated date ms: " + new Date(this.startDateMs));
  }
}

</script>
```

I would expect that my rendered object will have the same value as what I get on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. You are not allowed to use computed fields to initialize data fields. That explanation is enough for me right now to move on because I am a beginner in the JS/Vue.js fields.